# How to deploy existing java apps into Salesforce using Heroku

Tags: deployment, integration, heroku

I have some existing apps which are developed in Java, now I am planning to move the existing apps into Salesforce through Heroku. 
Is it possible to connect deployed java app on Heroku to Salesforce.

can some one cite few examples currently implemented.

Comment: What do you mean by you want to move existing apps into Salesforce through Heroku? Are you just looking to change where they're hosted or something more fundamental?

Comment: Mike, Thanks for your quick reply.                                                       Keeping aside SOAP and REST APIs, can Apps deployed on Heroku connect to Salesforce and manage its objects. When I say connect it means providing a custom software connector.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer is yes, and no.

There are two ways to connect heroku apps (regardless of the language) and salesforce.

1: the Salesforce Apis. There are a number of them but key api's are probably the Soap Enterprise and the Rest api. These allow for the exchange of data between your salesforce org and external applications (which can be hosted on heroku). You can find out more information on the use of these apis here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm (Soap) and http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/ (Rest)

2: You can develop a Canvas application which utilizes the Canvas toolkit and Javascript to expose your heroku based app within Salesforce. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/platform_connectpre/canvas_framework.pdf (Canvas Documentation)

Canvas would probably require more re-working of your application, than the APIs.

Without knowing more about the java applications you want to deploy to heroku and integrate with salesforce, I can't speak to the specifics of how that would work.

Comment: I have an application running on Google app engine and want to expose this application in salesforce with canvas. When I did this ,it shows error to load some css and also unable to post request to the application. I am very new to canvas app,so please guide me.